# Need help making a MKPointAnnotation a button

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase

i am not sure how to make the MKPointAnnotations a button i want to be able to click on the pop up to send me to another screen

```swift
import UIKit
import MapKit
import Firebase


//building the pin ticker


class mapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate{

    //class so an image can be added to point annotation
   /* class CustomPointAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation{
        var imageName: String!
    }*/
    @IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //set the map location to a specific location when the view loads
        let centerLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(39.863048 , -75.357583)
        //logingitude and latitude that the map will cover
        let mapSpan = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.001, longitudeDelta: 0.001)
        //range that the map will show
        let mapRange = MKCoordinateRegion(center: centerLocation, span: mapSpan)
        //what we will see on the map
        self.map.setRegion(mapRange, animated: false)

        addAnnotation()
        map.delegate = self

        let rotate = CGFloat(180)
        let regionradius : CLLocationDistance=300.0
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: centerLocation, latitudinalMeters: regionradius, longitudinalMeters: regionradius)

        //rotation that shows the map is aligned
        map.camera.pitch = rotate;
        map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        map.delegate = self
        map.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        //allows user to still interact with the items on map
        let pitch: CGFloat = 300
        let heading = 335.0
        var camera: MKMapCamera?
        camera = MKMapCamera(lookingAtCenter: centerLocation, fromDistance: regionradius, pitch: pitch, heading: heading)
        map.camera = camera!

        //disables clickables on map
        map.isRotateEnabled = false;
        map.isZoomEnabled = false;
        map.isScrollEnabled = false;
        map.showsCompass = false;
    }

    //funtion to create annotations
    private func addAnnotation(){
        let parkSpaceOne = MKPointAnnotation()
        let parkSpaceTwo = MKPointAnnotation()
        let db = Firestore.firestore()

        //grabs all the coordinates of the parking spaces in firebase
        db.collection("ParkingSpaces").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            } else {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    if let coords = document.get("coordinate") {
                        let point = coords as! GeoPoint
                        let lat = point.latitude
                        let lon = point.longitude

                        //string variable for spot field in firebase
                        let spotpone = document.get("spot") as! String
                        let spotptwo = document.get("spot") as! String
                        //if the spot in firbase matches the string then take the coordinates, add them to an annotation and place on the map
                        if (spotpone == "p1"){
                            parkSpaceOne.title = "P1"
                            parkSpaceOne.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lon)
                           self.map.addAnnotation(parkSpaceOne)
                        }
                        else if (spotptwo == "p2"){
                            parkSpaceTwo.title = "P2"
                            parkSpaceTwo.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lon)
                            self.map.addAnnotation(parkSpaceTwo)
                        }


                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapviewdelegate)

You can detect when the user selects an annotation:

```
func mapView(MKMapView, didSelect: MKAnnotationView)
```

> Tells the delegate that one of its annotation views was selected.

As well as

```
func mapView(MKMapView, annotationView: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped: UIControl)
```

> Tells the delegate that the user tapped one of the annotation view’s
>   accessory buttons.